# Java, многопоточночть, Sqlite

Tags: java, многопоточность

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class vacuum {
    public static void connect(String str) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:/data/" + str;
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("VACUUM");

            System.out.println(str + "ok.");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "db1.lgd";
        connect(str);
    }
}
```

Есть несколько Sqlite баз, которым нужно делать вакум.
Хочу делать вакум всем база в нескольких паралелльных потоках. 
Т.е. в метод connect передавать список баз из массива и сам метод запускать в отдельном потоке.
Выше, рабочий код, который делать вакум для одной базы.
Подскажите, это реализовать?

Comment: Выполняйте код метода connect в отдельном потоке, а с главного стартуйте эти потоки с нужными вам параметрами. В чём конкретно сложности?

Comment: Не работал с потоками. Можете показать пример ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно создать объект `Thread`, передать в него `Runnable` и запустить методом `start`, на Java 8 будет выглядеть так

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(()->connect("db1.lgd")).start();
    new Thread(()->connect("db2.lgd")).start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Согласно концепции параллельных потоков время выполнение каждого вызова метода connect() в большинстве случаев не суммируется. Порядок выполнения каждого из потоков определяется CPU и чисто теоретически, конечно, возможна ситуация, что второй поток начал выполняться ровно после того, как завершился первый. На практике же такая ситуация маловероятна, и в Вашем случае время выполнения чаще всего будет около 7 минут.

В дополнении к этому, советую в данном примере использовать не обычный Statement, а лучше [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) или [CallableStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html), так как оба sql-запроса имеют одинаковый синтаксис и будут прекомпилированы, что увеличит производительность.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо.
Сделал так:

```
public class vacuum extends Thread {
public static void connect(String str) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:/data/" + str;
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("VACUUM");

        System.out.println(str + " ok.");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(()->connect("db1.lgd")).start();
    new Thread(()->connect("db2.lgd")).start();
}
}
```

Так время вакумизации занимает такое же время, если бы делать вакум каждой базы последовательно. Т.е. db1.lgd - 7 мин., db2.lgd - 2 минуты. Если в многопоточном режиме то теже 9 минут получаются.